# Logo and Shortinstitute in beamer R Markdown

Tags: beamer, rmarkdown

How do we add a logo on a beamer in R Markdown title page? Also, how do I add the shortinstitute function for the footline in beamer R Markdown? Can someone please help with the correct commands.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the logo, what about `logo: image` ? Of course, plus a file named `image.png` of the desired size in the working directory.

MWE:

[image: mwe]

```
---
title: "My logo"
author: "Fran"
theme: Madrid
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
logo: image-example
output: beamer_presentation
---


## My text

This is all.
```

Similarly, for the short institute,  you can use `whatever: foo` in the header but using a custom template, where you change some like:

```
$if(institute)$
\institute{$institute$}
$endif$
```

to

```
$if(institute)$
\institute[$whatever$]{$institute$}
$endif$
```

Comment: +1: Very cool logo :).